# Passes use multi object array curl php

Tags: php, json, curl

may I know is the correct way, to pass curl PHP

```
$data6 = array (
"CorrelationId"  => 'CorrelationId',
"ConfirmationId"  => 'ConfirmationId',
"Contact.Title"  => 'Miss',
"Contact.FirstName"  => 'FirstName',
"Contact.LastName"  => 'LastName',
"Contact.MobilePhone"  => '1234567',
"Contact.HomePhone"  => '12356778',
"Contact.Email"  => 'admin@gmail.com',
"Contact.Remark"  => '',   
"Guests[0]Index"  => 1,
"Guests[0]Title" => 'Miss',
"Guests[0]FirstName" => 'FirstName',
"Guests[0]LastName" => 'LastName',
"Guests[0]MobilePhone" => '123456',
"Guests[0]HomePhone" => '+123456677',
"Guests[0]Email" => 'admin@gmail.com',
"Guests[0]Type" => 1,
"Guests[0]Age" => 21,
"Beds" => '',);
```

Below is the original JSON passes data, the original JSON data is from the postman, I running postman is good to go.
I think my mistake was from my code to pass parameter.

```
{
"CorrelationId": "CorrelationId",
"ConfirmationId": "ConfirmationId",
"Contact": {
    "Title": "Miss",
    "FirstName": "FirstName",
    "LastName": "LastName",
    "MobilePhone": "1234567",
    "HomePhone": "+6287717564805",
    "Email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "Remark": ""
},
"Guests": [
    {
        "Index": 1,
        "Title": "Miss",
        "FirstName": "FirstName",
        "LastName": "LastName",
        "MobilePhone": "1234567",
        "HomePhone": "+6287717564805",
        "Email": "admin@gmail.com",
        "Type": 1,
        "Age": 21
    }
],
"Beds": []
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes marliah, you can pass your array as follows. I suggest there's no need to add an extra brackets to guests. If you do, you have to use index 0 to access data. like `Guests[0][Age]`

```
<?php

$data = array(
    "CorrelationId" => "CorrelationId",
    "ConfirmationId" => "ConfirmationId",
    "Contact" => [
        "Title" => "Miss",
        "FirstName" => "FirstName",
        "LastName" => "LastName",
        "MobilePhone" => "1234567",
        "HomePhone" => "+6287717564805",
        "Email" => "admin@gmail.com",
        "Remark" => ""
    ],
    "Guests" => [[

        "Index" => 1,
        "Title" => "Miss",
        "FirstName" => "FirstName",
        "LastName" => "LastName",
        "MobilePhone" => "1234567",
        "HomePhone" => "+6287717564805",
        "Email" => "admin@gmail.com",
        "Type" => 1,
        "Age" => 21

    ]],
    "Beds" => []
);

print_r(json_encode($data));
```

You can use the following function to pass your array to the backend.
Don't forget to use `json_encode()`.

```
call('POST','API_URL',json_encode($data),'USERNAME','PASSWORD');
```

If you don't have any authentication setup at the backend, ignore the `$username` and the `$password`.
remove this line to ignore authentication credentials.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```

.

```
public function call($method, $url, $data, $username, $password)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    switch ($method) {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }
    // OPTIONS:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json",
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //Check for errors.
    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        //If an error occured, throw an Exception.
        throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
    }
    // EXECUTE:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Connection Failures");
    }
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo 'HTTP status: ' . $httpcode;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Kesara Karannaogada, thank you for your reply, after i update your code, I have the error {"Message": "An error has occurred."},

Comment: Did you use call function to send the array? if yes can you check the error HTTP status. you can print it using this.  $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
I'll update the code

Comment: the result is http status =0, is that correct $_POST $ContactTitle=$_POST['Contact']['Title']; and $GuestsIndex=$_POST['Guests'][0]['Index'];